# 'this' is not working in jquery (ajax)

Tags: jquery, arrays, ajax

I am using ajax to update the values in database .
I am getting response in th form of ajax but **$(this).val()** is not working properly

Take a look at my ajax call

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(".time_allocation_button").keyup(function(){
        //$(this).val('123');  //testing &  working
        var re = "";
        var data = {};
        data['time_allocation'] = jQuery(this).val();
        data['task_id'] = jQuery(this).data('task_id');
        data['project_id'] = jQuery(this).data('project_id');

        $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo base_url('project/add_time_frame_to_project_task');?>",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        data:  data,
        success: function(data){
            if(data.type == 'error'){
                $("#time_frame_error").html('<div class="callout callout-danger bg-red">'+ data.msg + '</div>');
                $(this).val(data.reset_value); //not working
                alert(data.reset_value);   // working
            }else{
                $("#time_frame_error").html('<div class="callout callout-success bg-green">'+ data.msg + '</div>');
            }
        },
        error: function(){
        }      

        });

    });
});
```

Comment: store as var _this = this, before ajax call

Comment: @HarpreetSingh I'm still not sure seeing all anwsers below and reading your comment WHY people don't use relevant `$.ajax` option instead?! `context: this`

Comment: @A.Wolff, I can admit, I am used to of it, also I am unaware of `context` flag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use relevant ajax option of `$.ajax` method to set relevant context, otherwise the context in ajax callback is set to ajax option object:

```
$.ajax({
    context: this, /*...*/
});
```

Comment: that does happen to be a good solution if using `$.ajax` directly, but it's not available when using the wrapper methods such as `$.get`

Comment: ah, that's new in jQuery 3.0 (but perhaps worked albeit undocumented in earlier versions?)

Comment: @Alnitak Well it is working in jq 2.2 but now checking the doc, you are correct, that's saying it is added in jq 3.0. On older version, global ajax object option could be used but... Indeed in this case, just setting a ref variable would be more readable

Answer (score 1):

In normal JavaScript every function invocation creates its own context variable (i.e. `this`) and unless special measures are taken the `list` in the nested inner function will be different to the one in the outer function.

The simplest solution is to assign the outer `this` and its jQuery object together as e.g `$this` and then use that variable in the inner callback:

```
jQuery(...).keyup(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    ...
    $.ajax({
        success: function() {
            $this.val(...)     // uses the variable from the outer scope
            ...
        });
    });
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are loosing `$(this)` inside of inner call, you should use something like $`this` to keep it

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
      jQuery(".time_allocation_button").keyup(function() {                
            var $this = $(this)
              //...
            success: function(data) {
                ///...
                $this.val(data.reset_value);
```

Comment: Wont work without `var`, as `$this` will be not a closure

Comment: sure it will work, but only so long as there aren't multiple invocations in progress at the same time or anything else that re-uses that variable.  Still not a good idea, though!

Answer (score 0):

the success function has an own context and an own this (the function itself)

You have to use a closure

```
jQuery(".time_allocation_button").keyup(function(){
   var that = this;
   // ...
   $.ajax({
       // ...
       success: function(data){
           $(that).val(data.reset_value); //not working
```

Answer (score 0):

The value of `this` changes, depending on the scope of your call. Directly inside the `keyup` handler, it refers to the element, inside the `success` callback of the ajax call, it does not.

The solution is to cache the reference outside of the `success` callback and use that within it.

```
jQuery(".time_allocation_button").keyup(function(){
   var $button = $(this);
   ....
    $.ajax({
            ....
           success: function(){
                $button.val("123");
           }   
           ....
          )
   ....
});
```